# Else without a previous if error

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
void repfunc(int (&number)[9],int(&m_no)[9],int (&stock)[9],int &size){

    FOR(i, 9-size, 9){

        stock_update(m_no,stock,size);


        if(number[i]==0){
            INCR(m_no,stock,i);
            FOR(z, i, 9){
                m_no[z]=small_in_stock(stock,1);
                int temp3=m_no[z];
                ++stock[temp3-1];
            }
            print(m_no);
            return;
        }

        int temp=number[i];

        else if(stock[temp-1]==0){
            m_no[i]=number[i];
            ++stock[temp-1];
            print(m_no);
        }
        else{
            int temp2=small_in_stock(stock,temp);

                if(temp2>0){
                    stock_clear(m_no,stock,i+1);

                    FOR(z, i, 9){
                        m_no[z]=small_in_stock(stock,1);
                        int temp3=m_no[z];
                        ++stock[temp3-1];
                    }

                }

                if(temp2<0){
                    if((i-1)<8-size){
                        INCR(m_no,stock,i-1);
                        size++;
                    }
                        FOR(z, i, 9){

                            m_no[z]=small_in_stock(stock,1);

                            int temp3=m_no[z];
                            ++stock[temp3-1];
                        }
                    print(m_no);
                    return;

                }
        }
    }
}
```

My compiler is giving else without previous if error in the else if part.

```
if(number[i]==0){
            INCR(m_no,stock,i);
            FOR(z, i, 9){
                m_no[z]=small_in_stock(stock,1);
                int temp3=m_no[z];
                ++stock[temp3-1];
            }
            print(m_no);
            return;
        }

        int temp=number[i];

        else if(stock[temp-1]==0){
            m_no[i]=number[i];
            ++stock[temp-1];
            print(m_no);
        }
```

The if part can be clearly seen. Is it due to the declaration in between. But why should a declaration cause problem? How to get around it?

Comment: Don't use…silly?…language-bending macros like `#define FOR(a, b, c) for(a; b; c)` without providing the definition.  Actually, don't use such macros, period. I'm puzzled what the `INCR(a, b, c)` macro provides — is that `#define INCR(a, b, c) ((a) = ((b) + (c)))`? Or is the assignment to `c` (or, perish the thought, `b`)?

Comment: That part in between is like a black hole, you can't put anything there and get it back.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler INCR is not a macro it is a function. int INCR(int (&m_no)[9], int (&stock)[9],int d2incr){
 int q=1;
 
 stock_clear(m_no,stock,d2incr+1);
 m_no[d2incr]=small_in_stock(stock,1);
 int temp=m_no[d2incr];
 ++stock[temp-1];
 
}
and Raxvan Thanks. "problem" solved

Comment: Do not use all caps for functions: it is an ancient tradition that ALL_CAPS means "here there be macros".

Comment: @Yakk it is a macro... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this line somewhere else.

```
int temp=number[i];
```

Secondly, `else` HAS TO BE immediately after the closing bracket of `if`. In your case, it is a declaration after `if`'s closing bracket.

Answer (score 4):

`int temp=number[i];` is set at an invalid postition. Move in front of the `if` or inside `else`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (...) {

}

int temp=number[i];

else if (...
```

The definition `int temp = number[i];` follows after the previous `if` and prevents the `else` from belonging to it, or anything else.  Hence the error. You'd have to move the definition before the `if` statement, or otherwise rethink the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the code where the error occurs:

```
if(number[i]==0){
    ....
}
int temp=number[i];
else if(stock[temp-1]==0)
{
    ....
}
```

You can only use `else` if it is the statement that immediately follows the `if`. And it is not. You have declared a new variable, `temp`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
int temp=number[i];
```

is at the wrong position.

```
if() {
   ...
}
```

Now there must immediately an:

```
else { ... }
```

If there is any other statement, you are outside your `if`-block and `else` is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is causing a problem is simply because it breaks the syntax rules for the language. The compiler assumes there is no `else` block if it doesn't follow **immediately** after the `if` block. You can put whitespace in between, but absolutely nothing else.

You've got 4 possibilities for where you could put that declaration line:

1. Before the whole if/else structure.
2. After the whole if/else structure.
3. Within the `if` block.
4. Within the `else` block.

I'd recommend the 1st one, or possibly the 4th (depending on whether you're using the `temp` variable later).

If you think about it logically, trying to put the declaration between the `if` and `else` blocks doesn't make sense. It makes it unclear if and when it actually gets executed in relation to the rest of the control structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(number[i]==0){
            INCR(m_no,stock,i);
            FOR(z, i, 9){
                m_no[z]=small_in_stock(stock,1);
                int temp3=m_no[z];
                ++stock[temp3-1];
            }
            print(m_no);
            return;
        }
```

// int temp=number[i]; ->>>> Place this statement in another appropriate position.
//else block shold follow the if block

```
 else if(stock[temp-1]==0){
            m_no[i]=number[i];
            ++stock[temp-1];
            print(m_no);
        }
```

So the code should be

```
if(number[i]==0){
                INCR(m_no,stock,i);
                FOR(z, i, 9){
                    m_no[z]=small_in_stock(stock,1);
                    int temp3=m_no[z];
                    ++stock[temp3-1];
                }
                print(m_no);
                return;
            }

     else if(stock[temp-1]==0){
                m_no[i]=number[i];
                ++stock[temp-1];
                print(m_no);
            }
```

place **int temp=number[i];** according to your logic

Answer (score 0):

This breaks the syntax of the if-else statement. You should move the declaration outside the if-else statement.

Comment: Which 'this' breaks the syntax?